# Defining a left-associative parser with PetitParser

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, petitparser

In http://pharobooks.gforge.inria.fr/PharoByExampleTwo-Eng/latest/, an ExpressionGrammar is defined. However, it is right-associative

```
parser parse: '1 + 2 + 6'.    ======> #(1 $+ #(2 $+ 6))
```

How can I make it left-associative so that

```
parser parse: '1 + 2 + 6'.
```

results in

```
#(#(1 $+ 2) $+ 6)
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For left associative grammars use:

```
term := (prod sepratedBy: $+ asParser trim) foldLeft: [ :a :op :b |
```

...]

For right associative grammars use:

```
raise := (prod sepratedBy: $^ asParser trim) foldRight: [ :a :op :b |
```

...]

Alternatively you might want to look at `PPExpressionParser`, that handles all the details automatically for you. You just tell it what operators are left-associative, right-associative, prefix, or postfix operators. Have a look at the class comment for a in-depth discussion.

Answer (score 4):

look at PPExpressionParser class.

it's designed for that and you have a great example in the class comment